# How to make an editable/typeable widget (like the Google Now search box)?

Tags: android, widget, android-appwidget

My first guess was to try `EditText` but it's not available for an AppWidget.
I did some research and found out that it's only possible on some selected HTC devices and that is not the solution I seek.

However I can see just the behaviour I want in the Google Now search widget - I tap on it and a keyboard appears. I can't seem to do it though.

Is there a way to do that? Or is it just reserved for Google-stuff and a couple devices which have such a mechanism implemented?

Comment: They are probably starting an activity that has a transparent background and an `EditText` in the right place. You might be able to use **`uiautomatorviewer`** to get a better idea of what they are doing.

Comment: Cheers, I'll accept that as an answer ;)